# Applying cointegration function from statsmodels on a large dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, cuda

I need to apply the [coint function from the statsmodels library](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.coint.html) to 207 times series with 1397 points each, two by two.

Currently, it takes between 35-40 minutes on my computer with an Intel 24 Cores CPU, last generation.

I tried to use Cython, or Data processing hacks from [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-speedup-data-processing-with-numpy-vectorization-12acac71cfca) but I get the exact same processing time.

Here is the code to reproduce it:

```
# Data generation (no improvement needed)
df_timeseries = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=2.25, high=2784.07,size=(1397, 207)))
# Downcasting to float 16 (could be unsigned too)
df_timeseries[df_timeseries.columns] = df_timeseries[df_timeseries.columns].astype(np.float16)
```

The cointegration function requires two time series, so I build a permutation of time series data frame column names:

```
from more_itertools import distinct_permutations as idp
# Shape: 42642 rows, 2 columns
df_permut = pd.DataFrame(idp(df_timeseries.columns, 2), columns=['ts1', 'ts2'])
```

Then, I apply the `coint` function to the permutation dataframe and extract only the `p-value` from the return (coint function returns `coint_t, pvalue, crit_value`):

```
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as st
df_permut["pvalue"] = df_permut.apply(
                        lambda x: 
                            [*st.coint(
                                df_timeseries[x['ts1']].values, 
                                df_timeseries[x['ts2']].values
                            )][1], axis=1)
```

This last part takes about 40 mins to run. I know that statsmodels is quite optimized and there is no chance I can imporved the `coint` method (I did try by extracting the code and removing the numerous unwanted check, but the linear regression runs from statsmodels take most of the time)
I don't believe there is many places for improvements on my code as the coint method is the most resource greedy.

How to drastically improve the speed? If there is no way, is that a path to move the coint method to GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is short, clear, and time consuming.

> How to drastically improve the speed?

You need to compute fewer figures.
For N time series you perform O(N^2) cointegration tests.

The OP does not describe the use case nor the observed data pattern.
Fortunately you *do* know what pattern the results showed,
since you patiently waited 40 minutes for the exhaustive comparison.

## break symmetry: 2x

Currently for each TS pair (a, b) you also test (b, a).
Consult your corpus of results to see if that's really necessary.
Many pairs, of course, will show no cointegration, in either direction,
showing no "hit".
Is there anything you know about each time series
that lets you predict in which direction we might see a hit?

For example, given a time series of Close prices you're
likely to also know its corresponding volume, volatility,
vertical segment, and which market it trades on.
Given hits from your results corpus,
there's an opportunity to do K-means clustering
to identify predictive features.

## autolag: 10x

By default we optimize an information criterion: AIC.
Running `coint` with `autolag=None` skips that,
so it runs an order of magnitude quicker.
Consult your results corpus to see if AIC produces
an important difference in the filtering result.

## common sense

Your results corpus might show for example that
a high volume stock will only forecast the price
of a low volume stock, or vice versa.
Or that only stocks within the same vertical
have predictive power for one another.
Prune your search space accordingly.

## simple features

The quadratic search is killing performance.
You want to be able to process each time series
exactly *once* to extract relevant features,
and *then* perform simple all-pairs comparisons.
One candidate is
[Change Point Detection](https://pypi.org/project/ruptures).

Sometimes an exogenous news event will affect a vertical
market, inducing immediate or delayed effects in
small or large players.
Set parameter K to a conveniently small number, like `1`.
Identify the K most likely Change Points in each time series,
sort them, and scan the sorted list of timestamps to identify
candidate pairs of time series to analyze.

---

tl;dr:

## Prune the search space.

There is knowledge, from the real world and from your results corpus,
that you can bring into this problem so you don't perform
a quadratic number of expensive analyses.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: `break symmetry: 2x` from the following q&a I understood that cointegration is non-directional but there might be cases where it can be, thus I test both (a, b) and (b, a): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300209/why-do-i-get-a-different-result-for-cointegration-test-when-i-swap-the-independe

Comment: `autolag` Just tested it with None and indeed it is 10 times faster, but the results are far too different

Comment: Oh, that PCA remark offers an interesting possibility!

Yeah, I had a feeling that lag details would show up differently in your source data than in my random data. The comment about "searching for optimal lag is **expensive**" still stands, though. Perhaps AIC finds just one or a handful of lags that matter to you, such as `7` and `30` ? You might be able to do a cheaper autolag search.

Comment: Thanks. After checking, the autolag is indeed the most greedy function. I improved it by computing just the `aic` value, splitting the processing time by two.